# What is the use of line integral in physics?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law, integration

Where and how is it used? Why is it used in Gauss's law?

Comment: Gauss' Law uses a surface integral, not a line integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A line integral is used whenever one needs to figure out how much of a vector has accumulated along a path.  The classic example is that work is expressed as the line integral $W=\int {\vec F}\cdot d{\vec x}$, which captures that idea of "accumulating work along the path", but the concept can show up in a lot of places.
2. Gauss's law is not phrased in terms of a line integral, but rather a surface integral.  Here, the concept is capturing "I have a ball, and I need to calculate how much electric field is leaving the ball".  You do this by calculating the little amount of electric field leaving each section of the ball, and then adding it all up.  This is naturally done with a surface integral.
3. In general, if you have a bunch of varying vector quantities, and you want to calculate numbers with them over a distance that is larger than a single point, you are likely going to have to do some sort of vector calculus.