# Difference in line integral and surface integral?

Tags: integration, calculus

What is the difference. Were are the used in physics?

Comment: the answer here is relevant https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649616/

Comment: well as the name implies, when calculating a line integral, you integrate over a line. E.g. the work done by a force over some path (line). for a surface integral, you integrate over a surface. e.g. you want the electric flux passing through a surface.

Comment: two good examples would be the work along a path and Gauss' Law

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line integral is an integral where the function to be integrated is evaluated along a curve.[image: Image Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif]

On the other hand a surface integral is an integral where the function to be integrated is evaluated along a surface.

[image]

There are many uses of line and surface integral in Physics I would highly recommend you to read this on math.libretexts.org

https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Vector_Calculus_(Corral)/04%3A_Line_and_Surface_Integrals

Answer (score -1):

[Line Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) gives **area** under the line (which may be of any shape) and [surface integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral) gives **volume** in a same way.

So in physics it's used whenever the shape is odd, and we want to find area or volume of the object with high accuracy.

Check out above mentioned wikipedia links for more details.

Comment: *Line Integral gives area under the line* not in the case of a vector field. not much interpretation of area there